# How to delete text after a given constraint?

Tags: python, sql, regex, python-3.x

So, I have a SQL file with the following content in it:

```
createtab_stmt
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
"  `name_id` bigint, "
"  `address_id` string, "
"  `full_name` bigint, "
  `insert_timestamp` timestamp)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
```

**I am trying to delete all text that comes after the ) in the third to last sentence ( "timestamp)" ). So the output should be everything before row format serde:

```
createtab_stmt
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
    "  `name_id` bigint, "
    "  `address_id` string, "
    "  `full_name` bigint, "
      `insert_timestamp` timestamp)
```

**This is my existing code:**

```
import re
f = open("/home/dir2/ddl", 'rt', encoding='latin-1')
words=f.readlines()

with open("/home/dir1/sampl7.sql","w") as output:
    for i in words:
        output.write(i.replace('"', ''))
```

Any ideas or suggestions? I'm not sure if regex is the best option or if there's a better way. Thanks.

Comment: does `words.replace('ROW.*','')` work?

Comment: @JuanC `AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @glibdud, right, it should have been `re.sub()`. But, by what @TrebledJ is saying, `words` is a list now. Could you post how `words` looks to you, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My method would be something like this:

```
f = open("/home/dir2/ddl", 'rt', encoding='latin-1')
source=f.read()

with open("/home/dir1/sampl7.sql","w") as output:
    output.write(source[:source.find(')')+1].replace('"', ''))
```

`.find()` will find the index of the character `')'` and we will use it to get the string from character 0 to that index (+ 1 to include the ')' itself).

Comment: Could also use `rfind` which would find the rightmost `)`.